# Unable to retrieve tables from SQL Server using Oracle's sql developer

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am unable to browse SQL Server tables using Oracle's SQL Developer. I am able to connect to SQL Server using SQL Developer, but when I try to expand the database in SQL Server, I get this error:

[image]

Comment: why you a not using ssms? or another tools for this - https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/

Comment: hi..thank you. we can use ssms for connecting, but the task is about connecting to microsoft sql server through sql developer. Connection has been succesful but unable to view the table because of the error mentioned.

Comment: one of the solution is downgrading to earlier versions of sql server, but that is not possible at our end. So kindly suggest any possible solutions.

Comment: try this .....take a new connection---->give connection name, username and password.---->give the portnumber and server ip address--->click on the retrieve database. are you able to get the database names. for image click [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1iH2e.png)

Comment: yeah thanks. we are done till there. we are able to retrieve database. but we cannot view any tables of database. the error is as above. invalid column name

Comment: Looks like it's a known issue with SQL Server 2014: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3698597?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

in newer version (Oracle IDE    19.2.0.206.2117 with Thirty party jtds-1.3.1.jar) of Oracle SQL Developer it is working.
Ivo.